# Porque el li a:hover no funciona

Tags: css

Como andan? Pruebo mi codigo en codepen y funciona perfecto, pero a la hora de ponerlo en mi proyecto, no funciona. Creo que tengo un error de Divs padres que no estoy viendo. Este es mi HTML:

```
<section class="wrapper style1">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div id="content">

                            <!-- Content -->

                                <article>
                                    <header>
                                        <h2>Organigrama </h2>
                                        <p></p>
                                    </header>
                                    <div class="organigrama">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>
                                              <a href="index.html">Director</a>
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a href="#">Director Ejecutivo</a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a href="#">Coordinador</a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Vicepresidente</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul> //EL CÓDIGO SIGUE....
```

para ahorrar código corte ahí. Y mi css:

```
  .organigrama li a:hover {
      border: 1px solid #fff;
      color: #ddd;
      background-color: rgba(255,128,0,0.7);
      display: inline-block;
  }
```

Gracias de antemano. Saludos!

Comment: Que error te muestra? o exactamente que no te funciona? ¿Probaste revisar desde la consola de windows?

Comment: @OtroBrayan no muestra error, solamente no muestra el color que corresponde cuando pasas por encima del li.

Comment: Si no podemos reproducir el problema, en poca cosa te podremos ayudar.

Comment: Estuve viendo tu código y a mi en `VS` me funciona pero fíjate en tu `HTML` que tu tag `<section>` no tiene el tag `</section>` para cerrarse por ahí es eso.

Comment: puedes utilizar "position: relative;" o algun otro de sus valores, tenia un problema similar y asi lo solucione

Answer (score 0):

Esto se produce por problemas en jerarquía en tu código, recuerda que CSS es en cascada, la ultima regla es la que se aplica, por lo que puede estarse sobre escribiendo.

Sumado a eso tienes los problemas de especificad de tu código, mientras mas especifico sea mayor peso y prioridad tiene al aplicarse.

Utiliza las herramientas de desarrollo de tu navegador para que veas que reglas están aplicando a esa parte de tu código, tanto firefox como chrome te mostraran las herramientas presionando F12